# Schema compare is not recognizing target source database objects

Tags: sql-server-2016, database-project, visual-studio-2019, schema-compare

I recently updated from Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise to 2019 Enterprise.  In my solution, I have a database project where I develop my tables, SPs, etc. and use "Schema Compare" to update my database in SQL Server.

When I open schema compare, connect to the target database in SQL server, and hit "Compare," it seems not to recognize objects in the target database because it lists every object in my database project to "Add" them to the target database in SQL Server despite the fact they already exist.

I tried opening my database project in Visual Studio 2017 (where I originally developed the project) and schema compare worked as intended.  The connection to the target database in SQL Server was the same.